# How to use different Storyboards for Full Screen / Split Screen / Slide Over in iOS 9?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, ios9

I am preparing my existing app for iOS 9. The app targets both iPhone and iPad and uses two different Storyboards for the two devices. The iPhone Storyboard uses a `UITabBarController` as root while the iPad Storyboards uses an `UISplitViewController` as root to work as Master-Detail view.

The SplitView is not designed to work with the new Split Screen and Slide Over functions in iOS 9. Actually the existing iPhone layout would work great in these cases. **But how do I tell Xcode / my app to switch from the iPad Storyboard to the iPhone Storyboard when ever SplitScreen or Slide Over are activated?**

Of course I know about `Size Classes` but as far as I know this only allows my to adapt the size and the position of views but to work with completely different views (like a SplitView in one case and a TabBar in another).

The SplitView and the TabBar are the biggest difference between the two storyboards, but not the only one. There are other difference like a slightly different user flow, etc. These things cannot be distinguished using Size Classes, can they?

So, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use size classes to have items installed and uninstalled!

[image: Story board install on size classes]

I would use the same storyboard and have the UITabBar installed with a compact width and the UISplitView installed with Regular width. However, this will cause the split view to show up on the iPhone 6 Plus in landscape orientation. Hopefully that is ok.